# Android downloading bitmap from url

Tags: android

I have another small problem,
I have a link to my picture in standard format however I need auth token at the end to access the image, so whenever I type it inside my webbrowser with correct auth token image is beign autimatically downloaded.
And here is my question, how am I suppossed to download such image in android to bitmap?
Because using

```
 final URL bitmapUrl = new URL(imageUrl);
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(70000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(70000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Auth_keyName", "Value");// if authentication required
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method to download bitmap

```
    public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bmp;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```